# java - Cannot get response from server socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I'm sending user credentials to be validated to server and server should respond this user credentials is valid or not. Server can get client's request. However client cannot get any response.

**All code about server side :**

**ClientHandler.java**

```
...

public ClientHandler(Socket socket) {
        try {
            client = socket;
            input = client.getInputStream();
            output = client.getOutputStream();
            inputHandler = new ClientInputHandler(input);
            outputHandler = new ServerOutputHandler(output);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
 @Override
    public void run() {

        inputHandler.start();
       outputHandler.start();
        String clientMessage = null;
        while(clientMessage == null) {
           clientMessage  = inputHandler.getClientMessage();
        }         
        System.out.println(clientMessage);
        User u = gson.fromJson(clientMessage, User.class);
        boolean successful = ClientAuthentication.validateCredentials(u);
        if(successful) {
            outputHandler.setServerMessage("1");
        }
        else {
            outputHandler.setServerMessage("0");
        } 


    }
...
```

**ClientInputHandler.java**

```
...
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                while ((clientMessage = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientInputHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
...
```

**ServerOutputHandler.java**

```
...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if(serverMessage != null) {
                 printWriter.println(serverMessage);
                 serverMessage = null;
            }          
        }
    }
...
```